# Full calendar event bind to custom button for next prev, month week and day view in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular, fullcalendar

I have used **fullcalendar** in my angular project.
I want to bind default methods like pre, next, month views, week view and day view to custom button.

Please help me with this.
[image]

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-api

Comment: @ADyson Not able to implement it in angular can you please share me more details of it ?

Comment: Well where exactly did you get stuck? Have you got some code you tried which caused an error? That would be easier to work with than just providing an example out of context. the fullCalendar angular documentation explains the basics of how to access any of these API functions when you're using the angular component - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular (the section titled "Calendar API").

Comment: @ADyson My buttons are custom button like as shown in pictures, as of now I'm not getting any error I just want to perform that functionality like view change next prev on custom button which are shown on top.

Comment: Well then you need to handle the click events of those buttons, and use the fullCalendar view API methods to control the calendar depending on what was selected. Again, it's unclear where you're stuck with that process. Have you actually tried anything at all? What specifically is confusing you?

Comment: Some of the methods in https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-navigation might be useful to you as well - I didn't mention it specifically but to be honest I was expecting by now you might have looked through the rest of the documentation yourself to see it there was anything else you needed.

Comment: @ADyson I got his methods but not getting how to integrate it in angular.
thank you for you time and advice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231102/discussion-between-manish-patidar-and-adyson).

Comment: "not getting" how, **specifically**? Do you understand how to detect a click on a button in Angular and run a callback function when that happens? I'm not an Angular expert but it should be easy to find that from tutorials etc. Do you understand how to use the fullCalendar methods from Anglular. (And - are you using fullCalendar's Angular plugin, or your own implementation?). It's really hard to help you because you're being unclear about what exactly the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution we need to do something like this.

```
someMethod() {
    let calendarApi = this.calendarComponent.getApi();
    calendarApi.next(); // For next
    calendarApi.prev(); // For prev
    calendarApi.changeView('timeGridDay'); // changing view
    calendarApi.changeView('timeGridDay', '2017-06-01'); // change view for specific date
    calendarApi.changeView('timeGrid', {
                         start: '2017-06-01',
                         end: '2017-06-05'
                    }); // For changing week view or month view accodring to date.
  }
```

**Thank you @ADyson for your time and support**

Answer (score 1):

Put the below code where you initialised the calendar.

```
this.calendarOptions = {


customButtons: {
   prev: { // this overrides the prev button
     text: 'PREV',
     click: () => {
     const calendarApi = this.calendarComponent.getApi();
     calendarApi.prev();
   }
   },
   next: { // this overrides the next button
     text: 'NEXT',
     click: () => {
     const calendarApi = this.calendarComponent.getApi();
     calendarApi.next();
    }
  },
   dayGridMonth: { // this overrides the month button
      text: 'Month',
      click: () => {
        const calendarApi = this.calendarComponent.getApi();
        calendarApi.changeView('dayGridMonth');
      }
    },
    timeGridWeek: { // this overrides the week button
      text: 'Week',
      click: () => {
        const calendarApi = this.calendarComponent.getApi();
        calendarApi.changeView('dayGridMonth');
      }
    },
    timeGridDay: { // this overrides the day button
      text: 'Day',
      click: () => {
        const calendarApi = this.calendarComponent.getApi();
        calendarApi.changeView('dayGridMonth');
      }
    }
}
```